# Magento 2 pop up view each refresh page

Tags: magento2, jquery

I have newsletter_popup show each time visitors refresh page ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/cookies',
        'jqueryfancyboxpack'
    ], function ($) {
        var check_cookie = jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup');
        if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
            popupNewsletter(); 
         }

        jQuery('#newsletter-popup .subscribe-bottom input').on('click', function(){
            if(jQuery(this).parent().find('input:checked').length){
                var check_cookie = jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup');
               if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                    jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup','dontshowitagain');
                }
                else
                {
                    jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
                    popupNewsletter();
                }
            } else {
                jQuery.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
            }
        }); 
    });

    function popupNewsletter() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $.fancybox.open('#newsletter-popup');
        });     
    };
</script>
```

also I enable Cookie Restriction Mode in Magento Default Cookie Settings

Answer (score 0):

please be more clear on your question, Newsletter popup is not showing every time or it is showing every time you refresh the page. Popup might be being cached. Please try to disable magento cache and check if it is working. If it is you need to skip caching for newsletter popup.

Comment: it is showing every time you refresh the page.

Comment: It must be caching issue , have you tried disabling cache

Comment: Yes but also same problem .